# How to fix Parsing error: invalid-first-character-of-tag-name.eslint (vue/no-parsing-error) in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, eslint, linter

Code

```
 <div class="flex justify-center">
            <vs-chip v-if="current" class="text-base w-24" :color="color">
              {{
                getPercentage > 0 && getPercentage < 3
                  ? "Neutral"
                  : getPercentage > 3 && current < average
                  ? "Buy"
                  : "Sell"
              }}
            </vs-chip>
          </div>
```

How can I fix this parsing error in vue ?

Is there a way to solve this without disabling the eslint rule ?
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: This [comment](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/370#issuecomment-830774152) might help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case by adding the following under the `rules` of `.eslintrc.js` worked:

```
"vue/no-parsing-error": [
    "error", 
    {
        "invalid-first-character-of-tag-name": false,
    }
],
```

---

PS: you may need to stop the server and run `npm run lint` for the rule to be applied

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions if you do not want to update eslint:

**Using v-text directive:**

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <vs-chip v-if="current" class="text-base w-24" :color="color" v-text="
    
      getPercentage > 0 && getPercentage < 3
          ? 'Neutral'
  : getPercentage > 3 && current < average
  ? 'Buy'
  : 'Sell'
  ">
  </vs-chip>
</div>
```

**Or using `&lt` replace `<`, and `&gt` replace `>`:**

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
        <vs-chip v-if="current" class="text-base w-24" :color="color">
          {{
            getPercentage &gt 0 && getPercentage &lt 3
              ? "Neutral"
              : getPercentage &gt 3 && current &lt average
              ? "Buy"
              : "Sell"
          }}
        </vs-chip>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better solved with a computed property instead of a nested ternary
(I'm assuming that `getPercentage`, `current` and `average` are either data or props, hence adding `this`)

```js
computed: {
  myLabel() {
    if (this.getPercentage > 0 && this.getPercentage < 3) {
      return "Neutral"
    } else if (this.getPercentage > 3 && this.current < this.average) {
      return "Buy"
    } else {
      return "Sell"
    }
  }
}
```

In component

```js
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <vs-chip v-if="current" class="text-base w-24" :color="color">
    {{myLabel}}
  </vs-chip>
</div>
```